# linux command to get the last appearance of a string in a text file

Tags: linux, awk, command, text-files

I want to find the last appearance of a string in a text file with linux commands. For example

```
1 a 1
2 a 2
3 a 3
1 b 1
2 b 2
3 b 3
1 c 1
2 c 2
3 c 3
```

In such a text file, i want to find the line number of the last appearance of b which is 6.
I can find the first appearance with

```
awk '/ b / {print NR;exit}' textFile.txt
```

but I have no idea how to do it for the last occurrence.

Answer (score 9):

```
cat -n textfile.txt | grep " b " | tail -1 |  cut -f 1
```

- `cat -n` prints the file to STDOUT prepending line numbers.
- `grep` greps out all lines containing "b" (you can use egrep for more advanced patterns or fgrep for faster grep of fixed strings)
- `tail -1` prints last line of those lines containing "b"
- `cut -f 1` prints  first column, which is line # from `cat -n`

Or you can use Perl if you wish (It's very similar to what you'd do in awk, but frankly, I personally don't ever use awk if I have Perl handy - Perl supports 100% of what awk can do, by design, as 1-liners - YMMV):

```
perl -ne '{$n=$. if / b /} END {print "$n\n"}' textfile.txt
```

Comment: @downvoter all answers are intended to give help. if some answer doesn't work, you could comment and help fix. I don't think any answer deserves downvote, particularly a working answer. just +1 to equalize.

Comment: I cannot understand such downvotes. Let's +1 another one, it is a good answer.

Comment: Voting can be interesting, I would give +1 for the perl but -1 for the pipeline so +0 overall but it's funny that a single downvote deemed 2 upvotes from users who would not a given those votes originally. This pretty much nullifies any meaning of the votes (both up and down). It's also interesting you didn't deem @fedorqui answer worth an upvote but where quick to complain where Kent only upvote his answer? You even said it yourself that the OP was happy with your solution so why complain about a +1 especially when you have over 50K rep.

Comment: I didn't downvote it but the N tools in a pipeline is the wrong approach (UNIX is NOT about using chains of small commands in a pipe when one command will do!) so I wouldn't be surprised that that got downvoted. As for perl doing everything awk can do - yeah, but it's not always there and the perl solutions posted are usually unnecessarily cryptic.

Comment: @sudo_O - lol frankly, my not upvoting the other answer was just concern that if you combine my answer being DVed and my UV of his answer, mine starts to look decidedly inferior judging by votes. I try to avoid tactical voting in general, but this DV got me less rational than usual.

Answer (score 3):

This can work:

```
$ awk '{if ($2~"b") a=NR} END{print a}' your_file
```

We check every second file being "b" and we record the number of line. It is appended, so by the time we finish reading the file, it will be the last one.

Test:

```
$ awk '{if ($2~"b") a=NR} END{print a}' your_file
6
```

Update based on [sudo_O advise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420541/linux-command-to-get-the-last-appearance-of-a-string-in-a-text-file/16420627?noredirect=1#comment23546397_16420627):

```
$ awk '{if ($2=="b") a=NR} END{print a}' your_file
```

to avoid having some `abc` in 2nd field.

It is also valid this one (shorter, I keep the one above because it is the one I thought :D):

```
$ awk '$2=="b" {a=NR} END{print a}' your_file
```

Comment: @Kent - out of sheer curiosity, what makes my solution "not right" if the OP himself commented that it works? :) [ please don't tell me that it's for lack of `awk` - OP's question explicitly asked for a Linux command, not an awk-only solution]

Comment: I think it is because my profile picture is nicer :D Funny enough, both work. I based my answer on awk because the OP showed some awk code. Also, I don't see what's bad on using awk instead of perl.

Comment: @DVK. :) ok, my opinion: 1) you used awk too (before you edit), but you have `cat, grep, tail and awk` they are not required. it is ok. 2) you `grep b`, works for op's example. but if you take a look OP's code: `/ b /`, he just wants to match the middle part (my understanding) `grep b` is a kind of massive killing.

Comment: @DVK sorry if I used inappropriate wording. I meant the "right"

Comment: @fedorqui - Nothing "bad", but it's easier to expand into full fledged program as needed if 1-liner was Perl from the get-go, so why pay the cost of re-writing awk to Perl later? Doing complicated stuff is harder for me in awk, though it may simply be because i'm a Perl developer and awk is just something I'm loosely familiar with.

Comment: Well, that depends on the language each one feels more comfortable working with. For me awk is very powerful and easy to update: small code does a lot. More or less like perl, I guess. I also do not like to pipe a lot of commands, so for example from your answer would prefer the `perl` part rather than the `cat | grep | tail | cut` one, also because it has to match the "b" in 2nd field.

Comment: @Kent - Fair enough. Though (1) building pipes out of component blocks is the underlying fundamental philosophy of Unix :)  . And Perl example was for when you want to save on spawning new processes :)  (2) Good catch, I didn't notice the spaces. Fixed.

Comment: @fedorqui - If I was doing this for myself, I'd use the Perl one as well. But OP asked for "Linux command" so building a pipeline seemed a good option to include as quintessential "Unix way" :)

Comment: @DVK I must say it again, I commented "right" on this answer, doesn't mean your answer is NOT right. concatenating commands with pipe is an nice thing in *nix world. someone prefers as less process as possible, someone enjoys using different tools/cmds to solve part of problem and get it done finally(kind of Divide and Conquer). If performance is not problem, both are **right**. I admit that I commented the "right" with personal preference.

Comment: @fedorqui the condition should be outside the block and it seems to me that string comparison is more appropriate here, this will avoid false positives such as `abc` i.e. `awk '$2=="b"{n=NR} END{print n}' file`

Comment: Thanks, @sudo_O! I tried to squeeze the if sentence but could not figure out how. Why should the condition be outside the block?

Comment: @fedorqui because that is the syntax of awk, `condition{block}` if the condition is true the block is executed. Of course you're original code was okay but this is the `awk` way!

Comment: Good one! Have to tell you I have a file with all these suggestions you give me. If I ever do a `cat` to this file my computer may have some problems handling so many lines :D Thanks!

Comment: +1 for having the right solution at the end of the list: `awk '$2=="b" {a=NR} END{print a}' your_file`.

Comment: @DVK wrt your question above `...why pay the cost of re-writing awk to Perl later` - you don't. Awk is a tool created specifically for text processing and so any text processing job can be done in it clearly and succinctly, you do NOT need to change to some other tool/language as the job gets bigger. If you have a job that is NOT text processing then you should not use awk - use shell or ruby or perl or whatever. I've been using UNIX for 31 years and haven't found a use for perl yet but YMMV.

Comment: @EdMorton - at least 20% of my "one-liners" end up as semipermanent Perl scripts, both in home use and in production at work. Since there's no real cost to doing it in Perl (vs awk) from the get go, due to the way Perl was designed at v1.0 as awk/sed replacement, I get all the possible upside and no downside. Not saying it will be true for everyone.

Comment: Yes, u/dvoting is very interesting sometimes. I normally don't first moment after sending mine. The first one having some u/dvote is normally the one having most of them, because I think people tend to see them with more confident eyes "ah, it got some votes, it must be *the good one*". All in all, I +1 @sudo_O comment because I also think it is a little funny how DKV was so inquisitive about Kent comment, as seen afterwards it was just some interpretation problem of "the right answer". By the way, he got his downvote way later than Kent comment so by that time our score difference was just 1.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach if $2 is always grouped (may be more efficient then waiting until the end):

```
awk 'NR==1||$2=="b",$2=="b"{next} {print NR-1; exit}' file
```

or

```
awk '$2=="b"{f=1} f==1 && $2!="b" {print NR-1; exit}' file
```